# How to push data from servlet to the jsp for perticular user

Tags: java, jsp, server

I want to achieve the scenario in which there are server 1 and server 2 and a client (browser).
When server 1 will get some update server 2 will be notified by server 1 and got some string from server 1 like - server 1 is updated and then server 2 will push this string to the JSP (Page should not be reload or refresh).

For example if userProfile.jsp is a secure page means this page could be seen by different users.

So how the servlet can push data to userProfile.jsp for particular user?

Please help.

Comment: consider a google search for "server side push" then if, per chance you were to click on the first link returned, you would end up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology.

Next step, read.

Answer (score 0):

A server can't push to a JSP, as the name implies **Java Server Pages** are processed on the server and the content resulting from their processing is passed to the client (usually a browser) who renders it.

What you probably want is to pass some JavaScript in the response that will pull regularly the server and ask whether there are any changes.